# How to pull customer data to calculate LTV from Facebook conversions?

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

I am working with a subscription company who is advertising on Facebook.

That means that the initial conversion is only a small portion of the revenue we ultimately collect from the customer.

Normally, for online conversions, we use UTM and other tracking tags in the URL to track conversions.  We do this by storing customer ID data in Mixpanel, along with the tracking tags.  Then we can easily pull that ID data from Mixpanel and use the ID data to pull out transaction data from our ordering system.

We are seeing significantly higher conversions from Facebook's internal reporting than we are seeing in Mixpanel, though.  We determined this is because Facebook's internal reporting is attributing sales to:

1. People who viewed the ad, ordered later, but never clicked
2. People who clicked on the ad, but didn't go through the entire funnel, and then ordered later from a different entry point or device.

We are currently sending over a `Completed Order` event which is mapped to Facebook's `Purchase` event.

Since these two groups don't have their tracking tags populated, I am wondering if there is some other way to retrieve the user's information from Facebook.  For example, if we pass over a `user ID` in our `Completed Order` event, will Facebook store that and allow us to pull that out?

Or is there another method we can use to better measure the value of these conversions over the long haul, since our tracking tags won't work?

Answer (score 0):

As you've known, Facebook can track the users who have viewed or clicked on an ad, then get converted a few days later (when the pixel is fired.) If you trust the reports provided by Facebook (you can call the insights API to get it also), there will be no problem.

The question is how you can track it separately. First, the insights API can take an attribution window, usually action_attribution_windows=['28d_click','1d_view'] by default, when calculation the conversions. If you change it to 1-day click and 0-day view, the result should be closer to what you tracked by yourself. But, is this what you actually want?

If you do not want to use Facebook's report, but want to do something like what Facebook does (like to track view-only users or later converters), you have several unlikely options:

1. Use some other options, like Atlas,
2. If you are a big advertiser with a Global Sales contact or a Facebook Marketing Partner, ask for some help from Solutions Engineer.

Nevertheless, probably to either downgrade the Facebook reporting to match yours by changing the attribution window, or to trust Facebook reports, are the most likely two options for you.